# Iterate through user logins while adding to a list AND outputting to console in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm working with managing Sharepoint online through Powershell, and I'm hitting a bit of a wall. To retrieve all user logins from a personal site, I use the command:

```
$UsersLogin += Get-SPOUser -Site $site | ForEach-Object {$_.LoginName}
```

This works fine, but I need to see each $._LoginName as it is being appended to my array. I have the option of running:

```
Get-SPOUser -Site $site | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.LoginName}
```

before running my previous command, but this doubles the runtime. I have also tried naively combining the two into:

```
$UsersLogin += Get-SPOUser -Site $site | ForEach-Object {Write-Host $_.LoginName}
```

And this outputted every login as I wanted, but didn't actually add anything in to my array. Does anyone have an idea as to how I can optimally achieve my goal? Much appreciated

EDIT: If this doesn't end up being an option, an equally good alternative is to print out updates on the size of my $UsersLogin array as it is being filled.. e.g. every time it gains 10 new users, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple lines of code within your foreach block; just separate each discrete line with a semicolon.

`Get-SPOUser -Site $site | ForEach-Object {$UsersLogin += $_.LoginName; write-host $_.LoginName}`